# Navbar no se muestra bien en el navegador

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, navbar

**Navbar no se muestra bien en el navegador, al momento de abrir el carrito en el lado derecho este se muestra incompleto, que debo corregir para que el proyecto se visualice bien?**

[image: esto sucede al momento de colocar el carrito en la derecha][image: esto sucede al momento de colocar el carrito en la izquierda. así es como quiero que se vea, pero en la derecha]

```html
<header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-stretch justify-content-between">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-info">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">UnicorShop</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"
                        aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <img src="img/ccomprar.png" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle img-fluid" height="70px"
                                    width="70px" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                    aria-expanded="false"></img>
                                <div id="carrito" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarCollapse">
                                    <table id="listascarro" class="table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Imagen</th>
```

Comment: Hola, que versión de Bootstrap usas?

Comment: hola,  Bootstrap v4.3.1

Comment: Muchisismas gracias, me funcionó a la perfección!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no interpreto bien tu código, veo que pones el icono del carrito de compra con una imagen y eso a su vez esta adentro de una lista, por eso se te oculta el box del carrito ya que este solo abarca todo el tamaño de la lista, le hice algunas modificaciones a tu código y lo integre como lo haría yo.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md justify-content-between">
  <!-- logo de tu pagina -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">UnicorShop</a>

  <!-- carrito de compra   -->
  <div class="btn-group">
    <img src="img/ccomprar.png" class="img-fluid" height="70px" width="70px" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></img>
     <div id="carrito" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
      
      ACÁ VA EL CONTENIDO DEL CARRITO.

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, suerte!